# Fetch Api Not working in certain conditions

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

This is my fetch code in js. I'm trying to validate a user on login but for that i currently have stored the login credentials in a login.json file in my system.Im trying to read the file but i keep getting the error

> TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."
>
> Note this only happens sometimes in other occasions the code runs
>   perfectly

This is my code..

```
fetch('../../shared/json/login-credentials.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            var loopvariable = 0;
            for (var user of data.users) {
                if (username == user) {
                    break;
                }
                loopvariable++
            }
            if (data.numberOfUsers <= loopvariable) {
                if (password == data.passwords[loopvariable]) {
                    form.submit();
                } else {
                    alert('Please insert a valid User name or Password');
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                alert('Please insert a valid User name ');
                return false;
            }
        }).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: What does the Network tab in the Dev Tools say? What is the actual status code of the request?

Comment: I dont  quite understand which information ure looking for is it this?                     304
GET
bootstrap.min.css
maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com
stylesheet
css
cached
118.36 KB
→ 60 ms

Comment: Nope, 304 just tells you've that file cached, search for the AJAX call to the json file.

Comment: Notice also, that who ever wants to, can load the public json file by just writing the path to the addressbar. I'd suggest you to rethink the entire logic here.

Comment: Thank you i get that i cant store sensitive information but im just doing a dummy app to try out how to read json . More importantly im a noob and I cant  find anything under XHR shouldnt  the AJAX call  be Displayed under XHR tab

Comment: On which browser are you testing? All the requests are shown at Network tab, make sure you're not filtering XHRs out of the list.

Comment: Firefox. I tried chromium i got this

Comment: login.js:42 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at validate (login.js:20)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (login.html:35)
fetch.then.then.catch.err @ login.js:42
Promise.catch (async)  
validate @ login.js:42
onclick @ login.html:35

Comment: and this  login.js:20 Fetch API cannot load file:///var/www/html/FrontEnd/Inventory-Management-System/shared/json/login-credentials.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
validate @ login.js:20
onclick @ login.html:35

Comment: Is that even a public directory where you've stored the json file?

Comment: No but it did work yesterday.. Like i said the code seems to work fine on certain occassions.. Ill make it public .. see what happens

Comment: There's something wrong in the settings of the server then, you should not be able to accces directories outside of the public root with some browser code.

Comment: Hmmm any ideas by the way the error still persists even after i made it public

Comment: Hey thanks i got it , I wasnt running it on the server